# How to load pdf file on CStatic control in VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, pdf, mfc

I want to draw/load `pdf` file which contain image, on the `CStatic` control in my VC++ project.

But, I don't know how to load pdf file on `CStatic` control.

I have searched a lot, but dint find any right direction.

In `Mac`, Its possible using specific function, but is there any way in `Windows` ?

Can you please suggest me any right direction...

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I want to load image in `PDF` to `CStatic`, reason behind that I want to maintain **image quality**. Just load `vector data` of `PDF image` to on `CStatic`.

Please suggest ... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to Show a PDF file inside a static control.
There are several ActiveX Controls that can show a PDF file. Also Adobe ships and AcroPdf ActiveX file that is free to use.
[Here is a sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9537/Adobe-ActiveX-Control-with-MFC)

If you just want to Show formatted data you can use an RTF-Control

Comment: I want to load image in PDF to CStatic. reason behind that i want to maintain image quality. Just load vector data of PDF image to on CStatic. Please suggest ... !!!

Comment: Even than! You Need something that shows a PDF... there is IMHO no way to show only an image from inside a PDF, except you extract the image.